# Improving the performance of an SQL query with many LEFT JOINs

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, left-join

I have a database structure serving up news articles with the following associations:

- HABTM news_categories
- HABTM tags
- HABTM uploads

I have written an SQL query to pull all this together:

```
 SELECT `news_articles`.*, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.title) AS `tags`, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.id) AS `tag_ids`,
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT news_categories.title) AS `news_categories`,
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT news_categories.id) AS `news_category_ids`,
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT news_categories.slug) AS `news_category_slugs`, 
 `news_articles_uploads`.`caption` AS `upload_caption`,
 `uploads`.`title` AS `upload_title`, 
 `uploads`.`basename` AS `upload_basename`,
 `uploads`.`extension` AS `upload_extension`,
 `uploads`.`path` AS `upload_path`
 FROM `news_articles`
 LEFT JOIN `news_articles_tags` ON news_articles_tags.news_article_id = news_articles.id
 LEFT JOIN `tags` ON news_articles_tags.tag_id = tags.id
 LEFT JOIN `news_articles_news_categories` ON news_articles_news_categories.news_article_id = news_articles.id
 LEFT JOIN `news_categories` ON news_articles_news_categories.news_category_id = news_categories.id
 LEFT JOIN `news_articles_uploads` ON (news_articles_uploads.news_article_id = news_articles.id AND news_articles_uploads.order = 0)
 LEFT JOIN `uploads` ON news_articles_uploads.upload_id = uploads.id 
 WHERE (news_categories.slug IN ("category-one","category-two","category-three","category-four","category-five")) AND (news_articles.published = 1)
 GROUP BY `news_articles`.`id`
 ORDER BY `news_articles`.`lead_article` DESC, `news_articles`.`created` DESC LIMIT 20;
```

The problem is that whilst the query runs, it is slow, and during busy periods the CPU usage is getting pretty out of hand!

Here is an EXPLAIN for the above query (right-click open in new tab to see full size):

[image: Explain result for the above query]

You can find the schema here: http://pastie.org/private/qoe2qo16rbqr5mptb4bug

The server is running MySQL 5.1.55 and the website uses Zend Framework to execute the query and PHP 5.2.8.

I've been through the MySQL slow query log and added missing indexes to the best of my knowledge but the query still shows up as taking 1-3 seconds to execute. If anyone has any ideas I've be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your "WHERE" clause originally included "AND" for your news categories within
a specified list, that would FORCE the joins to get there as INNER joins, not LEFT JOINs.
Also, I would try adding the "STRAIGHT_JOIN" clause.  This typically forces the engine
to do the joining in the order specifically stated, instead of trying to think of its own
alternative for you... especially when the other tables are more "lookup" references.

I would also apply the index as suggested by Jordan.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      NA.*, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.title) AS `tags`, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.id) AS tag_ids,
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT NC.title) AS news_categories,
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT NC.id) AS news_category_ids,
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT NC.slug) AS news_category_slugs, 
      NAUp.`caption` AS upload_caption,
      Up1.`title` AS upload_title, 
      Up1.`basename` AS upload_basename,
      Up1.`extension` AS upload_extension,
      Up1.`path` AS upload_path
   FROM 
      news_articles NA
         INNER JOIN news_articles_news_categories NACats
            ON NA.id = NACats.news_article_id

            INNER JOIN news_categories NC
               ON NACats.news_category_id = NC.id
               AND NC.slug IN ( "category-one",
                                "category-two",
                                "category-three",
                                "category-four",
                                "category-five" )


         LEFT JOIN news_articles_tags NATags
            ON NA.ID = NATags.news_article_id

            LEFT JOIN tags
               ON NATags.tag_id = tags.id

         LEFT JOIN news_articles_uploads NAUp
            ON    NA.ID = NAUp.news_article_id 
              AND NAUp.order = 0

            LEFT JOIN uploads Up1
               ON NAUp.upload_id = Up1.id 

   WHERE 
      NA.Published = 1
   GROUP BY 
      NA.ID
   ORDER BY 
      NA.lead_article DESC, 
      NA.created DESC 
   LIMIT 20;
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you have an index on `news_articles`.`lead_article`, `news_articles`.`created`, an index that has both columns.

```
create index news_articles_x1 on news_articles (lead_articles, created);
```

Without it, you won't be taking advantage of the order by limit clause, it would still scan and sort the whole table.

Also I would question whether you need all of this data in one blast?

Comment: +1 for "do you need all of this data in one blast" but you've missed out `news_articles.id` from your index...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I created the index byt the EXPLAIN result is still the same. Should I be seeing anything different?

Comment: The all the data in one go bit... I could probably loose the tags but def. need the categories and uploads joins.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I've added an index on news_articles.id